# Only select a <div> from an external page with Ajax/PHP

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, html, load

I've got a little problem. So, I'm using Ajax to load the content of another page into a `<div>`, after a change is detected in a `<select>`.
But the thing is, I only want to load a particular `<div>` from that external page into my main page. Here is the code of the main page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    createListeSelectWithDefault("categorie", <?php echo getJsCategorieListe()?>);
});
function showListes(str)
{
if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
  return;
  }
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","liste_result?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
<div id="content">
    <div id="bloc">
        <div id="title">Combiner</div>
        <div class="mx">
            <form name="new_combiner">
                <select id="categorie" name="categorie" onchange="showListes(this.value)"></select>
            </form>
        </div>  
        <div class="mx">
            <div id="txtHint">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is my external page:

```
<html>
    <div> some other kind of text, no need to post it here, but can't take it away</div>
<div id="mainDiv">
    <?php
    $q=$_GET["q"];
    $liste = getListeByCategorie($q);
    echo "<table border='1'>
    <tr>
    <th>Titre</th>
    <th>Vues</th>
    </tr>";

    foreach($liste as $row)
    {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row->titre() . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row->vue() . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
    ?>
</div>
           <div> some other kind of text, no need to post it here, but can't take it away</div>
```

So there you go, nothing more. What should I do? I only want the `<div id="mainDiv">` to be loaded into my page.

Comment: Since you're already using jQuery, why aren't you using its built-in AJAX handler instead of writing it yourself?

Comment: Use responseXml to get an Xml document back, then use the DOM to get the element you want from it.

Comment: Yes, please check [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax).

Comment: jQuery's `.load()` function would solve your problems.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I've actually never used AJAX, how does it work? I've been coding since a very long time (it does seem that way...:D) in PHP/MySQL and stuff, but I've never done much Javascript. So I've been looking through the internet trying to get this done, but how could I use AJAX do to it?

Comment: `xmlhttp.open("GET","liste_result?q="+str,true);` // just wanted to make sure you are calling your page correctly. are you really not using the .php extension?

Comment: Ok thanks for all those answers. So should I use the .load() or the AJAX? And how? Thanks!

Comment: Yes that's correct, I'm rewriting it, don't worry it's very secure, but thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please study the API more thoroughly. This particular use-case is already covered.

Look here: **http://api.jquery.com/load/**

(see the section on the page titled 'Loading Page Fragments')

From the API page:

```
$('#result').load('ajax/test.html #container');
```

This will load **only** the div with the id container, from the external page test.html, into the div with id result on the requesting page. Doesn't get any simpler than this (change the external doc selector as per your requirements).